# Regex group printing in bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl, regex

I want to use egrep on log file where it would only output me **matched** groups.

I've got in log file this:

```
queued as 6B6A72A7896   sent    00100000000000000   0       2019 Apr  7 00:37:39
```

using PCRE regex, I've matched important info.

```
(?P<"id>"(queued as [A-Z-0-9]{11}))+.+?(?<"div>"([0-9]{4}\s[A-Za-z]{3}.+?[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}))
```

see here: https://regex101.com/r/L1l396/1

How can I output only group ID and group DIV?

Answer (score 1):

**A solution using sed**

Changes:

- in the id part: `+.+?` -> `.*`
- in the date part: `.+?` -> `.*`

Output of your example input:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\(queued as [A-Z0-9-]\{11\}\).*\([0-9]\{4\}\s[A-Za-z]\{3\}.*[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\).*/id:\1 div:\2/p' file
id:queued as 6B6A72A7896 div:2019 Apr  7 00:37:37
id:queued as 25E642A7896 div:2019 Apr  7 02:12:02
id:queued as B4CCE2A7896 div:2019 Apr  7 02:26:49
id:queued as 247A22A7896 div:2019 Apr  7 02:28:25
```

Maybe this works for you?